# Why does Flutter throw a NoSuchMethodError in the console when trying to sign out of the app, even though it works in the simulator?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-navigation

I'm setting up the authentication flow for my Flutter app and everything is working smoothly in the simulator. The SignUp works well and the SignOut too. Despite working in the simulator, flutter throws a NoSuchMethod error when trying to log out.

**My LogOut Screen**

```
class Logout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ReusableCard(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          cardChild: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
            child: ReusableCard(
              cardChild: Text('Log out'),
              hexcolor: Colors.blueAccent,
              onPress: () async {
                await AuthService().signOut();
                Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    context, '/registration', (route) => false);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Relevant Code in Registration**

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    auth.getUser.then(
      (user) {
        if (user != null) {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/proddy');
        }
      },
    );
  }

                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Sign Up'),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        emailValid = validator.email(email);
                        passwordValid = validator.password(password);
                        if (emailValid == true && passwordValid == true) {
                          FirebaseUser user = await auth.createUserWithEmail(
                            email: email,
                            password: password,
                          );

                          if (user != null) {
                            await auth.updateUserData(user);
                            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/start');
                          }
                        } else {
                          print('Your credentials are invalid');
                        }
                      },
                      color: Colors.greenAccent,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                    ),
```

**The error message**

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY 
flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Start(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery,
flutter: InheritedProvider<FirebaseUser>]):
flutter: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
flutter: Receiver: null
flutter: Tried calling: uid
```

**Code pertaining to the error**

```
class Start extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String uid = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context).uid;
    SizeConfig().init(context);

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<GeneralInformation>.value(
          value: Database().generalDataStream(
            uid,
          ),
        ),
```

Thanks for any kind of help! I really appreciate it since I'm pretty much stuck  here :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put auth instead of AuthService() because auth is instance of FirebaseAuth and you should logout from it. **FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;**

```
onPress: () async {
   await auth.signOut();
   Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
   context, '/registration', (route) => false);
},
```

Comment: This does not change anything. I have defined the method signout inside my AuthService class. It simply returns FirebaseAuth.signout(). Do you have any other suggestions?:)

Comment: Hi @th8m0s if try to make FirebaseAuth.signOut() to FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()

Comment: Yes sorry, I have that. Unfortunately the weird error still persists. Note that when running the app inside of the simulator works perfectly. The error only exists in the console.